# Pure OpenGL on Windows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, opengl, cmake

I want to use OpenGL without GLFW, the docs say that I need to add `opengl32.lib` to linker dependencies.

How do I specifically import OpenGL and use it, where is `opengl32.lib` and how do I add it to my `CMakeLists.txt` or link in Visual Studio's properties?

Comment: It depends on the version of OpenGL you want to use. For any recent feature, you have to dynamically load OpenGL at runtime. `opengl32.lib` is useless for any OpenGL >=2 feature

Comment: @SpacePotatoes You can use all of opengl with just *opengl32.lib*. That dynamic loading is done with `wglGetProcAddress` which comes from *opengl32.lib*.

Comment: @van dench indeed you're right. I've forgotten this point, since I was using `glad` which dynamically loads `opengl32`.

Comment: @SpacePotatoes I have linked the <gl/GL.h> directory but it acts a bit weird, it gives me the defines but gives an error on everything else, also includes just fine. i have followed  dench 's comment but that answer states that i must also link to the header files and put dll files on my dir if needed but i don't know where the header files and the dll's are, i just put opengl32.lib into my linker->Additional Dependencies. Also i couln'd find wglGetProcAddress but thats not that important since everything i need is in gl.h

Comment: @user19068953 Whether you have included the header file `windows.h`? The Windows functions that support Microsoft's implementation of OpenGL in Windows must include the header file Windows.h.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, ~these are loafers~ this is not actually a great duplicate...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the find-module shipped with cmake using `find_package(OpenGL)`. When OpenGL is found, you can use the target `OpenGL::GL` to link your executable against `opengl32.lib`. See the [official doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenGL.html) for more targets.

```
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
add_executable(myApp main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myApp OpenGL::GL)
```